# Is this a good/bad way to load branch specific configurations in Zend Framework?

Tags: git, zend-framework, configuration

I've recently switched one of my projects to use git and I wanted to have the ability for each branch I create to have its own configuration options, for example I might be testing a change to the database in one branch so it should load a different db instance.

Prior to this I had a single application.ini file with [production], [staging : production] and [development : staging], it was under source control and each section included my login credentials to the db. Not ideal.

So now I've edited the application.ini to set a [default] section and a list of branches that are allowed to run the application. Here's a shortened version:

```
; application.ini

[default]
; Error handler settings
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0

[production : default]

[staging : default]

[master : default]

[dbupgradeidea : default]
```

In my `public_html/index.php` I now create a `Zend_Config_Ini` from this and set `'allowModifications' => true`.

```
$defaultConfig = new Zend_Config_Ini( 
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini', 
    null, 
    array( 
        'allowModifications' => true 
    ));
```

I then try to load the branch specific settings based on what environment the app is running in (set by .htaccess using `SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV <branch-name>`

For example the staging server sets it to staging.

```
try {
    $branchConfig = new Zend_Config_Ini(
        APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/branch-' . APPLICATION_ENV . '.ini'
        );  
} catch (Zend_Config_Exception $e) {
    die('/configs/branch-' . APPLICATION_ENV . '.ini file not found.');
}
```

My `application/configs` directory has a `branch.sample.ini` file with an empty parameter list of settings that should be defined by each branch. There is also an entry under `.gitignore` for `branch-*` so that branch specific settings are not included in the repository.

Now I merge the two configs together and convert to an array for Zend_Application:

```
$appConfig = $defaultConfig->merge( $branchConfig );
$appOptions = $appConfig->get( APPLICATION_ENV )->toArray();

// Include the Zend_Application class so we can start the App
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';  

$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV, 
    $appOptions
);
```

My production server is just the deployment of the production branch under git, the same for the staging server, and any local development I do is based on the branch that I've currently checked out.

I wanted to write a blog post about this, just in case it helped anyone out, but then I realized this could be a completely crappy way to do things and wanted to run it past you peoples first.

Please suggest better ways of achieving the same result, or if you think the process is fundamentally flawed, please point it out.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I solve this problem of **branch specific configuration** by using **stashes**.

### Proposed Workflow

**1. The preparation phase**

I'm on a branch (with no changes yet). I edit the configuration files and `git stash` them. Then I checkout a new branch and I edit the configuration files to my needs (for that specific branch).

**2. The actual use of the branch configurations**

When I switch branches and I want the configuration specific to that branch I do a

`git stash list`

to show all the stashes I have. To apply one of those stashes use:

`git stash apply stash@{1}`

(replace `1` with the actual number of the stash).
To work easier with the list of stashes you should give them a comment by using the command:

`git stash save "my branch <branch name> configurations"`

One word of advice: do **NOT** use `git stash pop` if you want to keep the changes in the stash list. Always use `git stash apply`.

Comment: That's a really nifty way of using stashes, hadn't thought about them in that way before.